# Tracking database changes

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Does anyone here can suggest a way to track database changes that were made through wordpress? For example I add a menu in wordpress, how can I keep track of this changes in database?

I use mysql
I tried searching and I only find toad and mysqldiff but still no luck. I also tried activating tracking for mysql but it only records changes that were made through phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger function in your mysql database. This function could copy the row before any UPDATE or INSERT statement into a separate table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

BUT! Write a small IF check into your procedure so that you can disable it. Otherwise you will have a hard time when importing data through sql scripts during development.

A sample:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `backup`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `backup`
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `sourceTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF @disableTriggers <> 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO `backupTable` (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (OLD.col1,OLD.col2,OLD.col3)
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```